# How to tell if a 16 bit-binary encoded value is increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, binary, encoder

I'm trying to determine if a number is increasing or decreasing. An encoder gives back an unsigned 16-bit value that will either increase, decrease, or stay the same if the encoded data increases or decreases.

I obtain the encoded value and append it to a list every x seconds, and I'm trying to compare these values to see if they're increasing/decreasing. I check each value to the previously obtained value, but the only problem I'm having is that at 65535, the data wraps back around to 0. How would I account for these instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implausible that the value changes by more than half of its total range between measurements (if it does, you can't figure out which way it's moving), so if you get a difference greater than 32,768 subtract 65,536 from it, and if you get a difference less than -32,768 add 65,536 to it.

That way, if the value goes from e.g. 65,535 to 2 (a raw difference of -65,533) you will register as a difference of +3 (= -65,533 + 65,536), which is what you wanted. The same process happens in reverse if you cross the wrap-around the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine a limit on the amount the data can increase between readings.  Then check to see whether that has been exceeded.  For instance, if your limit is 100, and the previous value was 65500, you need to check whether the new value is in either the range 655001-65535 *or* 0 - 65.

For instance:

```
if new_val > old_val or \
   new_val < (old_val + tolerance) % 65536:
```

... where `tolerance` is the maximum increase you want to recognize.